# npm run deploy occurs error 'includes' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, deployment

I have been trying to deploy my changes to GitHub repository, but there is an error.

```
Failed to compile.

Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

The commands I run:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'upgrade'
npm run deploy
```

I always used to deploy that way.
I have installed some node and webpack `devDependencies`, after that this error occurred.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.4.2",
    "emailjs-com": "^3.2.0",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "gsap": "^3.8.0",
    "locomotive-scroll": "^4.1.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-gsap": "^3.2.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
    "react-locomotive-scroll": "^0.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.4",
    "sass-loader": "^12.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.1",
    "use-in-view": "^1.0.15",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2",
    "webpack": "^5.60.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.43.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a bug in your JS code, which you have not shown. (There is no problem with your Git repository.)

Comment: @torek What should I do now?

Comment: Got me - show some code, give people access to your repo, something along those lines.

Comment: @torek I am new to react js. could you please tell me what code should I share?

Comment: I don't know, I don't write reactJS code. But "undefined" is the value of an unset variable in JavaScript.